# Website conversion help - UTF-8, Covering all the bases... functions, metas, and sql utf-8

Tags: php, xhtml, utf-8, multibyte-functions

You all did such an amazing job answering a question earlier I thought - I'll ask this one before I get too deep in my conversion only to find out I did something wrong.  I only have 3 pages to a website I'm making for myself.  It has forms, sqli db.  I was told to use UTF-8 (I partially did, but not fully) lol.  Ok, sounds cool.  Now that I want to fix it to be 100% UTF-8 aware I have already written about 1,900 lines of code in PHP, JS, and HTML without using multibyte functions.. SO... here's my question...  in my conversion I have done this... (snippits of code from various places...)

**PHP**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto'); // sets the timezone to Eastern Stand Time
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

etc

**SQL**

(from cpanel interface) MySQL connection collation": utf8_general_ci

**SQL DB** (still in pre utf-8 mode)

username    varchar(50) latin1_general_cs

companyname varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci

fname   varchar(25) latin1_swedish_ci

I have NO valuable data in the tables.  I will be changing those to one of the following (I'm not sure which one however)...

utf8_general_ci
or
utf8_unicode_ci

While I would like to make the site available for foreign people, it's not a high priority BUT, since I'm doing it UTF-8 style it's probably already going to work for foreign languages.

**My questions are...**

**1)** I set my timezone, i didn't set my locale in php because I have never done that.  Do I need to do that?  How do I do that for my Toronto/Canada Location?

**2)** Is setting each page via meta tag ok enough to make the entire page UTF-8

**3)** By using the meta tag does that mean all my form fields are already being input as UTF-8 data?  If not, how do I change it so they are.

**4)** Which one do I use for my DB?  utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci

**5)** I NEED certain things to be case sensitive.  I only see ci for utf8.  Is this because a "Dave" is different than "dave" so using multibyte compares automatically compares case...??!?!?!

**6)** My DB currently has say 50 characters for storage for ASCII stuff - I assume that by switching to utf-8 in the DB that for english people like myself that 50 storage will be fine - but if some foreign person comes along and enters a bunch of weird symbols I would need to increase my storage by x4 to accomodate all the extra bytes for unicode?  I don't mind using up more storage but I'm curious how the proper way to allocate this would be.  And since it's a VARCHAR(50) would it really matter anyways?  If the name is "Dave" it would be 4 characters.  If it was some foreign name, "Dave" in symbols might be 12 characters!  lol. So, if I allocate say 100 to the username field that should do since it's unlikely ALL characters would be 4 bytes.  Or, just set it to x4 what I would for english and make them all VARCHARS to save space.  When they enter data on the form I'll be using MB_LENGTH functions (I forget the exact function) so I would still be able to control how many characters would be input.

**7)** How can I test my unicode website?  I have never used anything other than beautiful english :) lol.  How can I switch my browser? to pretend like I'm from somewhere else and enter a pile of codes and see if my functions work once I re-write them to use mb_ (multibyte) functions.  Or, is there nothing to switch over... I just type in ALT 245 or something and I get symbols?!?!?  I don't know how to enter foreign test characters!  It would suck to get english working only to have all foreign customers not able to enter a password because I didn't test my website enough :)

**8)** I know to use certain functions ctype, mb_ to handle unicode compares, strings, etc.  Any surprises in store for me?  Things that don't work as they should?

Yes... I'm wordy!  :)  I use Dreamweaver CS3 but that shouldn't matter.  There is no UTF-8 characters embeded in my actual files.

Awaiting all your wisdom...

Comment: I don't get your first question. What do you mean be local. Locale?

Comment: Yes.  Locale.  I fixed the spelling! :)  If the website is all UTF-8, I guess for those functions I have to also specify locale and there is a function called setlocale or something - do I need to use that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with some of the answers:

2) Your server should also send headers that indicate that the content sent is in UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

3) Browsers will send their data in UTF-8, yes. But hackers may not, so you should also in your `htmlententies` and similar HTML-encoding function give the UTF-8-Charset (see [example exploit](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/dec/google-xss-example))

5) A case insensitive collation does only mean that when doing a WHERE-clause, case doesn't play a role.

6) Actually, it is the contrary: in ASCII you may need a bigger VARCHAR than in UTF-8 ("Dave" is 4 chars, 4 bytes; "ǝʌɐp" is 4 chars, 8 bytes.)

Comment: Cool, thank you for those tips!  2) Didn't know you could send headers with content type as well.  3) Thank you, I'll keep in mind to set utf-8 in all my function calls.  5) Good to know!  6) How did you enter that upside down?  lol.  I might be able to use how you did that to test my website.  lol.

Comment: Some weeks ago I saw a stackoverflow user with a flipped username, so I searched ... and found: http://www.revfad.com/flip.html

Comment: thats really cool source code on that flip page.  Looks like they use /u0279 for an alt character.  They also seem to use Arial Unicode Font.  Never thought about the fonts before....  I'll see if there is a Verdana Unicode font...  hope so, that's my favorite.  lol.

Comment: That pretty much answers most of my questions except the database ones.  Thank you for all your tips!

Answer (score 0):

1) About the [Set locale information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) , it can affect in some string functions (i.e. `strtoupper()`), its purpose is affect and changes the way some "things" operate.
For example within a Regular expression, it changes the way of `\w \W` (Word characters) are expected.
But As more and more applications change  to  using  Unicode, the need for this locale support is expected to die away.

7) [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) can help you a little bit.

About testing characters and pretend you are another person from China or another place:

**index.php:**

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"><!-- This tag encode the text that will be typed within a text area (If the accep-charset="" is not speciefied)
If the character typed isnt part of the encoding the character will be escaped**-->
</head>

<form method="POST" action="encode.php" accept-charset="UTF-8"><!--accept-charset"" is used to set the encoding that will be used to transmit the characters over a form-->
<p><textarea name="input" maxlength="256" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea></p>
<p><button>Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

**[Escaped Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#h-5.3)

Then in the **encode.php** you can controll your input with:

```
$input=$_POST["input"];
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give all these things a try.  What I'm curious about is HOW do I enter foreign codes on the keyboard?  Is it similar to ALT 243 to get that ASCII symbol?  If I'm trying to type in weird symbols how do I do that?  Change windows itself to UTF-8? and then type /#73634 or something?!  I have no clue how to bring up anything other than english and some ascii characters by holding ALT and typing a number from 0 to 255.  Unicode should be different, or maybe it's the same.  lol  I'm lost!  lol

Comment: Is the same if you type from a chinese keyboard that if you "create" a chinese character, the issue is how those bytes will be stored, and then interpret them correctly with the properly encoding. About the ALT+ here is an good article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

Comment: I have been testing the site with the changes and all seems to be ok.  The only thing I opened up by my changes was a SQL injection attack by not using statements since I now can't filter everything thats not a-z A-Z and 0-9.  I figured if you could never enter symbols you could never hack it but now that this massive door is open I don't feel as secure as I did before.  How do I know there isn't 200 ways to show a quote.  Ah well.   Once I switch to statements it should be just as secure as it was before.  Thank you all for your time.  I appreciate it! I tried voting up others but I can't...